# SalesForce - How to allow a Custom Object to be edited in visual force page

Tags: salesforce

How do I show an edit button for a custom object in a visual force page and allow the user to edit the custom object?

Answer (score 1):

in your page create a button:

```
<apex:commandButton action="{!MyEdit}" value="edit">
     <apex:params value="{!theIdOfTheRecordToEdit}" name="MyId" assignTo=”{!theId}” />
</apex:commandbutton>
```

in your controller create a global parameter and an action
  public String theId {get;set;}

```
public pagereference MyEdit() {
   return(new pagereference('/'+theId+'/e'));
}
```

The 'magic' is in the '/e' at the end.